Consolidating Repeating Rows & Removing Duplicates
I am using SQL to store Log Data. Inside the Log Data there are repeating or duplicate consecutive rows that I would like to condense into a single row. The new row needs to reflect the start and end time of the block of repeating or duplicate consecutive rows as well as the number of times that it repeated. However I still want to distinguish when the rows change.
Example:



TimeStamp
Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D
Column E




Time1
2
2
2
2
2


Time2
2
2
2
2
2


Time3
9
9
9
9
9


Time4
2
2
2
2
2


Time5
2
2
2
2
2


Time6
8
8
8
8
8


Time7
8
8
8
8
8


Time8
2
2
2
2
2


Time9
2
2
2
2
2


Time10
2
2
2
2
2



Wanted Result:



StartTime
EndTime
Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D
Column E
NumOccur




Time1
Time2
2
2
2
2
2
2


Time3
Time3
9
9
9
9
9
1


Time4
Time5
2
2
2
2
2
2


Time6
Time7
8
8
8
8
8
2


Time8
Time10
2
2
2
2
2
3



This is Result I'm getting:



StartTime
EndTime
Column A
Column B
Column C
Column D
Column E
NumOccur




Time1
Time10
2
2
2
2
2
7


Time3
Time3
9
9
9
9
9
1


Time6
Time7
8
8
8
8
8
2



I tried this but did not get the result I wanted:
SELECT MIN(TimeStamp) AS StartTime, MIN(TimeStamp) AS EndTime, Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D, Column E, count(*)
FROM table
GROUP BY Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D, Column E,
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1

I also tired implementing a Partition as well but with limited success
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT MIN(TimeStamp) AS StartTime, MIN(TimeStamp) AS EndTime, Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D, Column E
ROW_NUMBER () OVER(Partition by Column A, Column B, Column C, Column D, Column E
ORDER BY TimeStamp) RowNum

FROM table
) d

I attempted using the min and max but it did not work.

Search for "gaps and islands".  (A specific dup question link to follow shortly.)

(Had it right the first time...) This is a gaps-and-islands problem.  See this answer.  I took the liberty of converting that solution to match your data in this db<>fiddle, but with some real dates filled in.

CRME
CREATE TABLE Log (
  Timestamp datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate(),
  ColumnA int NOT NULL,
  ColumnB int NOT NULL,
  ColumnC int NOT NULL,
  ColumnD int NOT NULL,
  ColumnE int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Log (Timestamp, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE)
VALUES
  ('2024-04-30 17:10:01', 2,  2,  2,  2,  2),
  ('2024-04-30 17:10:02', 2,  2,  2,  2,  2),
  ('2024-04-30 17:10:03', 9,  9,  9,  9,  9),
  ('2024-04-30 17:10:04', 2,  2,  2,  2,  2),
  ('2024-04-30 17:10:05', 2,  2,  2,  2,  2),
  ('2024-04-30 17:10:06', 8,  8,  8,  8,  8),
  ('2024-04-30 17:10:07', 8,  8,  8,  8,  8),
  ('2024-04-30 17:10:08', 2,  2,  2,  2,  2),
  ('2024-04-30 17:10:09', 2,  2,  2,  2,  2),
  ('2024-04-30 17:10:10', 2,  2,  2,  2,  2)

SELECT * FROM Log;

Range de-duplication
WITH markedChanges AS (
    SELECT
        TimeStamp,
        ColumnA,
        ColumnB,
        ColumnC,
        ColumnD,
        ColumnE,
        CASE WHEN LAG(ColumnA) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) = ColumnA AND
                  LAG(ColumnB) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) = ColumnB AND
                  LAG(ColumnC) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) = ColumnC AND
                  LAG(ColumnD) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) = ColumnD AND
                  LAG(ColumnE) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp) = ColumnE
             THEN 0
             ELSE 1
        END AS ChangeFlag
    FROM Log
), groupedRows AS (
    SELECT
        TimeStamp,
        ColumnA,
        ColumnB,
        ColumnC,
        ColumnD,
        ColumnE,
        SUM(ChangeFlag) OVER (ORDER BY TimeStamp ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS GroupID
    FROM MarkedChanges
), aggregatedResults AS (
    SELECT
        MIN(TimeStamp) AS StartTime,
        MAX(TimeStamp) AS EndTime,
        ColumnA,
        ColumnB,
        ColumnC,
        ColumnD,
        ColumnE,
        COUNT(*) AS NumberOfOccurrences
    FROM GroupedRows
    GROUP BY GroupID, ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC, ColumnD, ColumnE
)
SELECT
    StartTime,
    EndTime,
    ColumnA,
    ColumnB,
    ColumnC,
    ColumnD,
    ColumnE,
    NumberOfOccurrences
FROM AggregatedResults
ORDER BY StartTime;

Before
| Timestamp               | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnE |
|-------------------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
| 2024-04-30 17:10:01.000 | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:02.000 | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:03.000 | 9       | 9       | 9       | 9       | 9       |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:04.000 | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:05.000 | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:06.000 | 8       | 8       | 8       | 8       | 8       |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:07.000 | 8       | 8       | 8       | 8       | 8       |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:08.000 | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:09.000 | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:10.000 | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       |

After:
| StartTime               | EndTime                 | ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC | ColumnD | ColumnE | NumberOfOccurrences |
|-------------------------|-------------------------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------|---------------------|
| 2024-04-30 17:10:01.000 | 2024-04-30 17:10:02.000 | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2                   |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:03.000 | 2024-04-30 17:10:03.000 | 9       | 9       | 9       | 9       | 9       | 1                   |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:04.000 | 2024-04-30 17:10:05.000 | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2                   |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:06.000 | 2024-04-30 17:10:07.000 | 8       | 8       | 8       | 8       | 8       | 2                   |
| 2024-04-30 17:10:08.000 | 2024-04-30 17:10:10.000 | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 2       | 3                   |

dbFiddle

Thank you so much works exactly as intended!

Don't forget to accept an answer so i get the points!
